# How to include the command in the output file?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have been reading quite a lot of information about stdin, stdout and stderr. I get the mechanism.
But how do I include the command I type in, and the result to the output file?

###### Example

If I type in the following commands,

```
echo Hello! > abc.txt
cat abc.txt > finalOutput.txt
```

When I open `finalOutput.txt` I want to see,

```
cat abc.txt
Hello!
```

I have tried,

```
cat abc.txt 0> finalOutput.txt
cat abc.txt > finalOutput.txt 0>&1
```

###### Question

I know there are other methods such as script, logsave, bash, etc. But is there a SINGLE command (not too chunky) to record both INPUT and OUTPUT of a command, and write them into a file?

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to see _cat abc.txt_, but you do NOT want to see _echo Hello!_???

Comment: In addition, what would you like to see in your finalOutput.txt, if the cat command where `file=abc.txt; cat $file >someFile.txt`?

Comment: You might want the [`script` command](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=script&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: `_()(echo "$@";"$@")` ? Then: `_ cat abc.txt > finalOutput.txt`

Answer (score -1):

**Simplest Answer**

You can use `set -x` in the script such that every line evaluated will be output.   You can then run the script externally to log to a file like

```
# test
#!/bin/sh
set -x
echo "Hello World!"
```

```
$ ./test
+ echo Hello World!
Hello World!
```

You would then use this like: `./test > finalOutput.txt`, perhaps from a wrapper/debug script?

**More Complicated Solutions**

- I came up with `exec &> >(tee finalOutput.txt)`, it's close to logging all output to a file from within the script, but there's a buffering problem that makes it hang.  I'm not sure how to handle that here.

Comment: This would not write anything into _finalOutput.txt_.